# Why does my EditText got expanded horizontally or vertically after setting Width and Height as wrap_content in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm newbie to android. So I'm struggling with the following problem.

1.after set `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"` in EditText, it got expanded vertically.

2.after set `android:layout_width="180dp"` in EditText, it got expanded horizontally.

Is there anyway to set my EditText fixed? Ex: If am going to type a long email address in EditText, font size of the text should get shrinked based on long text instead of EditText getting expanded. is there any possibility to achieve this task?

here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 

tools:context="com.vadmin.myrx.SendReport">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Doctor Email"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:hint="example@xyz.com"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_oval"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Phone"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:hint="+91 0000 000 000"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@drawable/text_oval"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Report"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:text="Save"
       android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
       android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"

       />
```

Thanks
Anita

[image]

Comment: Are you using an image as it's background?  Post your XML

Comment: I'm a bit lost.. did you EditText instead of TextVew ?

Comment: The image you added shows the alignment issues. Add whole of the XML for this.

Comment: @AnitaShalu use LinearLayout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this layout instead of your layout:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.vadmin.myrx.SendReport" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Doctor Email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="example@xyz.com"
            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="+91 0000 000 000"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Report"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have used your XML and modified it. Just add your images. I removed it as I wasn't having them.

**EDIT**: I have added `android:inputType` for editTexts as well + and put a limit on phone number (12) and email (20), you can change them according to yourself.

Comment: The bottom closing tag closes the one at the top

Comment: Hey man @Tushar your idea worked now. But still am facing little pblm. i.e) when i enter xxxxxxyyyyx1990@gmail.com in textView, I can only view gmail alone. Unable to view remaining text..

Comment: @AnitaShalu yes we can, as many as we want BUT it's better to use as less as you can (for better performance). And don't worry about the text, it's a horizontal scroll, if you move the scroll horizontally, you'll see it.

Comment: I edited the answer and replaced it with the old one. Yes, you can use it. Tested the view on two devices, it works fine! Are you by any chance using emulator?

Comment: thanks a lot buddy...really you did a immense help..sorry the fb id which is mentioned in ur profile leads me to visit "https://www.facebook.com/True.Gamers.Official" this link..

Comment: if you dont mind can you give me ur gmail id? then only i can ask you doubts. it is not safe to chat in public portal i think..

Comment: What is going on here? [chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71661/android-discussions)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by replacing in your layout

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Doctor Email"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:hint="example@xyz.com"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/text_oval"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:hint="+91 0000 000 000"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_oval"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Report"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"

        />
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this too..but textView got expanded vertically. But I dont need any expand. I just want to fix my textView as always even if i enter a long email address

Comment: may i knw what is that single_line=true means?

Comment: @AnitaShalu, Single_line, as name suggests makes you enter only in one line, when you press the enter key, the keypad closes or moves t next view BUT doesn't expand the edittext horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `EditText` with below code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:hint="example@xyz.com"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_oval"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    />
```

Comment: hey i did..but still that editText view is expanding like i posted my image below

Comment: I edited my code. Please try now. You need to specify the layout of editText that it should be to the right of textView1.

Comment: The EditText code above. Added these lines: `android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following property on the TextView fixed this weird issue for me. This should be the default behaviour of the textview in my opinion.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

Answer (score -1):

In [Libraries For Developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en) you will find more than one AutoScaleTextView variants and several code snippets in StackOverflow that achieve this (If I understood you correctly)

Comment: Pointing someone that states he is a newbie to a repository of open source libraries that can handle similar situation is an eye-opener in many cases. I didn't want to write this as a comment because at the same time I was commenting her to better explain the question. The vote down here is a bit nasty IMHO